# Show that there is no integer solution to $\frac{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^b - 1}{2^a - \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^b}$ other than $a = b = 1$.

Tags: integers, binary

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$. How to show that there is no other solution to
$$
\frac{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^b - 1}{2^a - \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^b} \in \mathbb{N}
$$
other than $a = b = 1$ ?

My attempts so far:

I solved for $\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^b$:

$$
\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^b = \frac{2^ac + 1}{c + 1}
$$

Then I equaled the numerator and the denominator such that:

$$
\begin{align}
3^b &= 2^ac+1 \\
2^b &= c + 1
\end{align}
$$

which is forming combined the equation:

$$
3^b = 2^{a+b} - 2^a + 1
$$

Then I looked for the binary representations of these numbers. The right hand side is regulary splitted in three regions. Some 1 at the beginning, some zeros following and a single 1 at the end. But now I stuck because I cant find asimilar regularity in $3^b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your last equations as:
$$ 3^b - 1 = 2^a(2^b-1)$$
Assume that $a>1$. Then the RHS is divisible by $4$. Note that when $b$ is odd the LHS is $2$ modulo $4$ which is a contradiction. So $b$ must be even, eg $b = 2x$. Then $2^b-1 = 4^x-1 = 0 \mod 3$. This means that the RHS is divisible by $3$ but the LHS clearly isn't. So we have that $a$ must be equal to $1$.

Can you finish from here?

Comment: $4^x-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ was the missing part.

Comment: Glad I could help. It's a common trick to assume the opposite of what you know. Also note that you could end up in the same conclusion by factoring $3^b-1$ as a difference of $b$ powers.